# What happened with the death of the Butcher?

Tags: estoy-vivo

At the end of the third season, during a shootout with the Butcher, who has somehow returned from the dead again, Vargas puts a bullet in the middle of his forehead. When he does so, the Butcher immediately falls down dead (for the third time, I suppose). Then, so far as I can tell, the bodies of all the dead Liasons evaporate, as do all the living ones. To cap it off, Carlota revives from her deadly gunshot wound.

- In previous seasons, the death of the Butcher only killed the people who had been possessed by him, killed, and then resurrected (or killed, resurrected, and then possessed, depending). It did not even kill the people he controlled without killing, since the classmate of Beatriz did not die but instead was released from his control. But the Liasons died and evaporated at the moment of his death.
- In addition, it took special weapons from the Pasarela to kill him, or any of the hostile entities, the first few times. This was specifically stated. This time, he was killed with a regular gun.
- Also, it seems a bit strange that Carlota would come back to life with the Butcher's death....

What is going on here?